# Deleted comb space proof

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove that the deleted comb space, $X$, is not path connected.
We've defined $A = [0, 1] \times \{0\} \cup \{(\frac{1}{n}, t) : n \geq 1, t \in [0, 1]\}$, $X = A \cup \{(0, 1)\}$.

From lectures we have the following first part of the proof:

> Let $p = (0, 1)$, $q = (1, 1)$. Suppose that $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow X$ is continuous with $f(0) = p$, $f(1) = q$. Let $R = f^{-1}(p) = \{t \in [0, 1] : f(t) = p\}.$

A confusing note has been made regarding $R$ saying "this is the number of times we hit $p$".

How does this make sense? (I suspect this actually means that $R$ is the times that we hit $p$, not the number of times.)

Later on a note says that $R$ is closed because it is a singleton point in Hausdorff space, and that $0 \in R$. Why is $R$ a singleton point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1.$ It turns out that we did indeed mean that $R$ is the set of times at which we hit $p$.

$2.$ It is not $R$ that is a singleton point in Hausdorff space that makes it $R$ closed, but rather that $p$ is a singleton point in Hausdorff space and $f^{-1}$ is the preimage of a continuous function.